# CSS - Hide Nav Bar & Footer

Tags: javascript, css, laravel, uiwebview

I'm looking to hide the navigation bar and footer within a GoNative.io App. I'm not familiar with CSS at all but I have tried this:

```
nav.navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-fixed-top {
display: none !important;
}
```

And several other variations but it just won't hide it.

Here is the layout of the site

[image]

I'm a bit confused how the structure needs to be laid out in order for adding custom CSS to hide this.

Comment: add `id = 'nav-bar'` inside `nav` tag and in your css  -   `#nav-bar{display:none;}`

Comment: Have you tried applying the CSS styling using Chrome DevTools (or your browser's equivalent live CSS editor)? Does it work from there?

Comment: @asemahle Yes, via chrome I can right click and hide the element, or add display: none and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.navbar{
     visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the selector should be only nav.navbar or just .navbar

nav.navbar{
   }